# A problem related to $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(x-f(x))dx=1/12$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

> Consider  a differentiable  function satisfying $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(x-f(x))dx=1/12$$ Then find the nearest integer less than or equal to $\frac{1}{f'(1)}$.

---

Let $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x)(x-f(x))$$ we notice $F(1)=1/12$ , $F(0)=0$ and $$F'(1)=f(1)-{f(1)}^2$$
What do i do next?
I have tried using LMVT and Rolle's but not getting anything nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can manipulate $$\int_{0}^{1} (4xf(x)-4f^2(x)) \, dx=1/3$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} (4xf(x)-4f^2(x)-x^2) \, dx=1/3 - \int_0^1 x^2 dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} (2f(x)-x)^2 \, dx=0 $$

$$\Rightarrow f(x)=x/2 $$

Comment: Thanks i should have guessed  something of this sort . Is my answer also correct not that they are very different

Comment: Yes. It's correct and nice! +1

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @cosmo5  for inspiration we have in general $$ab\le \frac{{(a+b)}^2}{4}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)((x-f(x))\le \int_{0}^1 \frac{{(f(x)+x-f(x))}^2}{4}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{4}=1/12$$
For equality to hold $$f(x)=x-f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$$