# Find the area bounded by $y=f(x)$ from $x=1$ to $x=3$ where $f(x)$ satisfies the equation $\int_0^1(x-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac1{12}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, indefinite-integrals, area

> Find the area bounded by $y=f(x)$ from $x=1$ to $x=3$ where $f(x)$ satisfies the equation $\int_0^1(x-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac1{12}$

I tried solving $\int xf(x)dx$ by taking $f(x)$ as first function, I get $$f(x)\frac{x^2}2-\int f'(x)\frac{x^2}2dx$$

I also tried solving $\int (f(x))^2dx$ by taking $1$ as the second function. I get $$(f(x))^2x-\int 2f(x)f'(x)xdx$$

I don't think I am reaching anywhere.

Comment: I guess $f$ has all the good properties we need (continuity, differentiability,..)

Comment: @Falcon I guess the same. I have posted the question verbatim.

Comment: related but stronger conditions : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902825/a-problem-related-to-int-01-fxx-fxdx-1-12?noredirect=1

Comment: I don't know how the given information about $\int_0^1$ would ever let us extract information about $\int_1^3$.

Comment: I agree with @Arthur: this question cannot be answered ! Check the text of this homework. Maybe you have forgotten information like "$f$ is a first degree polynomial" ?

Comment: @aarbee As you are far from a newcomer on this site, please answer us...

Comment: @JeanMarie I just checked that there is no extra information given on f. BFur4list has posted a link above. I think using that, we can find f here. So, maybe no extra info is required

Comment: @aarbee The link provided shows that $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ on [0,1]. But, assuming continuity in point $(1,1/2)$, you can connect in that point the curve of **any** function defined on [1,3] such that $f(1)=1/2$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie I see your point now. We do need extra info. But alas, that's not provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have
$$\int^{1}_{0}(x-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac{1}{12}.$$
Let's do the following manipulations:
$$\int^{1}_{0}(4x-4f(x))f(x)dx=\int^{1}_{0}(4xf(x)-4f(x)^2)dx-\frac{1}{3}=0.$$
Notice that $$\int^{1}_{0}x^2dx=\frac{1}{3},$$ we can plug this above:

$$\int^{1}_{0}(4xf(x)-4f(x)^2-x^2)dx=-\int^{1}_{0}(x-2f(x))^2dx=0.$$

If $f(x)\geq 0$, then $\int^{b}_{a}f(x)dx=0$, implies $f(x)=0$. (I am assuming this)

Thus: $-\int^{1}_{0}(x-2f(x))^2dx=0$, then $x-2f(x)=0$, therefore:
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}.$$

Finally we need:$$\int^{3}_{1}\frac{x}{2}dx=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \bigg(x-f(x)\bigg)f(x)=g(x)$

$\displaystyle xf(x)-(f(x))^2=g(x)$

$\displaystyle  (f(x))^2-xf(x)+g(x)=0$

For real roots , We have $\displaystyle D\geq 0$

$\displaystyle x^2-4g(x)\geq 0\Longrightarrow g(x)\leq \frac{x^2}{4}$

$\displaystyle \int^3_0 \bigg(x-f(x)\bigg) f(x)dx=\int^1_0g(x)dx\leq \int^1_0\frac{x^2}{4}dx=\bigg(\frac{x^3}{12}\bigg)^3_0=\frac{1}{12}$

Equality  hold when

$\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}\Longrightarrow (f(x))^2-xf(x)+\frac{x^2}{4}=0$

$\displaystyle \bigg(f(x)-\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2=0\Longrightarrow f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$

Now area enclosed by the curve $\displaystyle y=f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$,

$x=1$ and $x=3$ is $\displaystyle A=\int^3_1 f(x)dx=\int^3_1\frac{x}{2}dx=\bigg(\frac{x^2}{4}\bigg)^3_1=\frac{9}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=\color{blue}{2}$