# Find $f'(1)$ given $\int_0^1f(x)(x-f(x))\,dx=\frac1{12}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Consider a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
> $$\int_{\ 0}^1 f(x)(x-f(x))\,dx=\frac{1}{12}.$$
> Then find the value of $f'(1)$

After banging my head on the table for half an hour, I assumed the function to be of the form $\frac{x}n$ where $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Solving it gives the result $n=2$. So the value of $f'(1)$ comes out to be $0.5$ which is in agreement with the answer.

What is the proper method of solving this question$?$ Mine was a luck but I hope there must be a mathematical method existing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does "solve the definite integral" mean here?

Comment: @DanAsimov umm idk... I thought it was a catchy title... should I edit it??

Comment: To be clear:  what you describe does not solve the problem.  All you have done is to show that a particular function that has the right integral leads to the right value.  Presumably there are many, many functions that have the same integral and you need to show that all of them have the same value of $f'(1)$.

Comment: @lulu yeah you're right but I don't know how to prove that

Comment: Consider $0 \le \int_0^1(x/2-f(x))^2dx$. Hence $\int_0^1 f(x)(x-f(x))dx \le 1/12$. What happens if $f$ is continuous but is not the function $x \mapsto x/2$?

Comment: Have you considered using a power series of the form $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{ lim_{i\to\infty}} a_{i}x^{i}$ to generalize the answer?

Comment: @Gerd how did you come up with that function?? And why the statement after hence follows?? Pls elaborate

Comment: @StephenElliott no....I don't know much about power series

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^1 f(x)(x-f(x))dx=1/12$ then $f(x)=x/2$, since otherwise the integral is $< 1/12$. Just expand the integrand $(x/2-f(x))^2$. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902825/a-problem-related-to-int-01-fxx-fxdx-1-12

Comment: @Gerd thanks....so the main motive was to convert it into a perfect square?? And what do you think about the am-gm inequality method??

Comment: Yes, converting into a perfect square is the idea. I think it is the fastest way to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A problem related to $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(x-f(x))dx=1/12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902825/a-problem-related-to-int-01-fxx-fxdx-1-12) It shows that $f(x) = x/2$ and then your problem is complete. Note that, if you want "intuition" for why something like this works, then remember that just an integral identity should not be enough to determine the function $f$, unless there is a functional inequality lurking underneath.

Comment: Since there is no condition which makes $f$ continuous, maybe there is no $f'(1)$...

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I see....but I think that the best method given here is the am-gm one...cuz it is still somewhat practical and not like the perfect square one